# Update Git Repository after fixing error without pulling

Tags: git

I have a repo for project A, I had to do another project B which has a lot of things common with Project A. I made a copy of project A files, I however forgot to delete the .git folder so after making updates to project B, I used git push origin master (thereby pushing all updates to repo of project A mistakenly). I collaborate on project A with someone else. I removed git origin from project B to avoid further mistake. My collaborator on project has however pulled the changes and made modification and updated the repo. I tried to do

```
git reset --hard previousCommit
```

I then added new modifications to make the project to it is meant to be. The challenge I now have is to push to the repo. When I try to push to the repo. I get the error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The repo requires that I pull first, and that returns me to the original state of the problem. How do I resolve this please?

Comment: You would have to push with `force` but of course that is going to screw up your collaborator. Basically everyone needs to stop work, agree on what goes into this repo, make it so, and clone afresh.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind